# Cookies not working for password-protected Pages on WordPress

Tags: php, authentication, wordpress, password-protection

Initially I had the issue reported in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054245/how-to-make-a-custom-template-in-wordpress-work-as-a-password-protected-page).

Now, what I noticed is that there are some browsers that accept the password, and there are some which don't. Difference? For some reason the cookie is generated when I log in into the Administration module, but it isn't when I write down the password to access the page, forcing it to simply reload.

I can see the cookie created for the log-in, but I can see none for the password-protected Page.

These happens on Internet Explorer, both version 7 and 8; only on some machines, though, but most of them fail this. I already tried white-listing the URL, and even letting it accept ALL cookies, to no avail.

What may be the cause? If perhaps it's got something to do with question above, please help me!

Thanks in advance.

PS: If you know of another, cookie-free method to make a simple authentication, please link me to it. Thanks. Oh, and by the way, this is inside an Intranet with static, class C IPs.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by the cookie isn't generated when you "write down the password to access the page"..  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: When you password protect a Page/Post, it will ask you for a password previously set up in the system. When you give it such password, it should generate a cookie, but currently it doesn't. In any case, sorry if I didn't make myself clear: English isn't my forte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on an Apache server, consider this authentication module for Wordpress that allows for a far more flexible approach:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/http-authentication/

This module allows you to Bypass WordPress' normal authentication and use Apache's authentication instead - So pretty much any auth you'd like to use.

You can find more information on Apache Authentication methods here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#database

I've pointed at the database section as I'm assuming you'll want to use a database to authenticate.

Comment: I'm using nginx, but your suggestion made me have a look at it, and it also has a basic HTTP authentication module. Thank you very much for remembering me about it!